# I can't get the data from my Reactive form Ionic 6.12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to receive my data from my reactive form, I added the formControlName, also the FormBuilder, but the console.log shows empty object like the photo

**Result**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpnLT.png)

**My Code**

```js
export class InscritComponent implements OnInit {

  ins:FormGroup;

  constructor(private forme:FormBuilder) {
    this.ins=this.forme.group({
      title:['',Validators.required]
    })
   }

   get title(){
     return this.ins.get('title');
   }
  

  logForm()
{
  console.log(this.ins.value);
}

  ngOnInit() {}


}
```

```html
<ion-content>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>S'inscrire</h1>
        <img src="../../assets/da.png" />
    </div>

    <form id="form" [formGroup]="ins">
        <ion-item class="bord">
            <ion-label position="floating">text</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" formControlName="title"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-button expand="block" (click)="logForm()" shape="round ">inscrit</ion-button>
    </form>


</ion-content>
```

Comment: try using settimeout method

Comment: how can i  do it !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule` to *app.module.ts* or/and *yourcomponent.module.ts*